# The sample counter app fails - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written the following sample counter app using react.js. `onClick` fires the `handleAddOne` but the value of `count` never gets incremented.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleAddOne = this.handleAddOne.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            count : 0
        };
    }
    handleAddOne() {
        console.log('handleAddOne');
        this.state.count++;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
                <h1>Count:{this.state.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleAddOne}>+1</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react, state is an immutable object, meaning you are supposed to set state values using only setStste function and not directly.

```
 <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({count:this.state.count++})
 }}>
  +1
 </button>
```

Comment: State can be immutable. But variables are mutable, if I am not wrong. Why just `this.state.count++` doesn't work

Comment: Count is an inner object of state. So that too is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest, you should be using `setState` to trigger the state change and rerender.

However, when using `prevState` it is also recommended that you use the functional version of `setState`

```
handleAddOne() {
    console.log('handleAddOne');
    this.setState(prevState=>({
        count: prevState.count+1
    }));
}
```

Documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: Because `state` is not a normal javascript concept. React uses a push based state updation system that needs you to use `setState` to trigger a re-render

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read more about `Reactjs` from https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html

```
handleAddOne() {
    console.log('handleAddOne');
    this.setState({count: this.state.count++})
}
```